# What's is a "Android Resource File"?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Can someone provide me an understandable definition for "Android Resource File"?

[image: Android Studio Menu]

The following dialog confuses me even more:

[image: Menu 2]

What is considered as a "Resource Type" by them?

Comment: See this link https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources

Comment: @SonTruong I you like, then turn your comment into an answer. I will accept it.

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android, a resource is a localized text string, bitmap, layout, or other small piece of noncode information that your app needs. At build time, all resources get compiled into your application.

The resources locates inside `res` directory of your app. The Android resource compiler processes resources arcording to which subforder they are in and the format of the file, for example:

- `res/drawable`: Contains all resources file that can be drawable, such as (.png, .jpg, .gif) or xml file.
- `res/layout`: Contains all resources file that defines user interface layout, such as `activity_main.xml`, `fragment_login.xml`.
- `res/color`: Contains all resources file that defines list of colors that used in your app.
- `res/value`: Contains all resources file that contains simple value like string, integer, etc.
- ...

For more information, please see [App resources overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources) and [Resourcce types overview](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources),

Answer (score 2):

Resource files hold extra content e.g. `bitmaps, layout definitions, user interface strings, animation instructions` that the app implements within its own code.

Resource types are held within resource files and are found in the project resource directory under `res/`. Find more information here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/available-resources